# Strange character comparison- unequal character are equal

Tags: java, validation

Following simple code should escape characters with except mathematical symbols, lower cases and few other symbols like `~`.

```
public class Sample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Sample sample = new Sample();

        String expr = " ( a , + b )/..[c3 ";
        System.out.println(sample.clear(expr, true));
        //OUT: (a+b)/[c

        expr = "(a+b)/{}c";
        System.out.println(sample.clear(expr, true));
        //OUT: (a+b)/}c

        expr = "(a+b)/][c";
        System.out.println(sample.clear(expr, true));
        //(a+b)/[c
    }

    public String clear(String line, final boolean isInfix) {

        line = line.trim();
        line = line.replaceAll("\\s", "");


        for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++) {

            char c = line.charAt(i);

            if (!(Character.isLowerCase(c) || isAllowedSymbol(c, isInfix))) {

                line = line.replace(Character.toString(c), "");
            }

        }

        if (line.isEmpty()) return null;


        return line;
    }

    private boolean isAllowedSymbol(char c, boolean isInfix) {

        char allowed[] = {'~', '^', '*', '/', '%', '+', '-', '<', '>', '!', '&', '|', '='};
        char infixAllowed[] = {'~', '^', '*', '/', '%', '+', '-', '<', '>', '!', '&', '|', '=', '(', ')'};

        char chars[] = allowed;
        int maxRange = allowed.length;

        if (isInfix) {

            chars = infixAllowed;
            maxRange = infixAllowed.length;
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < maxRange; j++) {

            if (c == chars[j]) {

                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

}
```

Why following input characters causes so strange and incorrect output?

Characters like `{` `}` and `]` `[` should be removed.
Example:

```
IN
 ( a , + b )/..[c3 
(a+b)/{}c
(a+b)/][c

OUT
(a+b)/[c
(a+b)/}c
(a+b)/[c
```

Runtime:

```
% java -version                                             
java version "1.8.0_66"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_66-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.66-b17, mixed mode)

% javac -version
javac 1.8.0_66
```

Running under Arch x64

Comment: You're rewriting `line` as you iterate it, you need to backtrack when you remove characters.

Comment: I think this is a bit confusing code: (!(Character.isLowerCase(c) || isAllowedSymbol(c, isInfix))). Anyway, you want to remove from the string all the characters that are not mathematical symbols, lower cases and something like ~?

Comment: @LorenzoBarbagli This way of solve problem was not subject of Task. I might change this, but I do not want change code too much. Posted problem should be replicable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you're removing offending characters from the input string, then continuing to iterate by character index.

So (in the second example), when `i` equals 6, you remove the nonmatching "{", then the `line` variable contains the string "(a+b)/}c". Then you continue through the `for` loop with `i` equal to 7, which checks the "c" character.

Because you've removed a character from the string, you never check the "}" character.

Let me spell it out a bit more. Here's the `line` variable before the loop iteration where `i` equals 6:

```
012345678
(a+b)/{}c
```

In that loop iteration you're inspecting the "{" character, and you correctly identify that it should be removed, so at the start of the next iteration (`i` equals 7), here's `line` again:

```
012345678
(a+b)/}c
```

Now, since `i` is 7, this iteration will check the "c" character, so as you can see, you never inspect the "}" character.